# How to test if there is newline after each nextLine() when reading from a file?

Tags: java, file-io

What I'm trying to do is when I read from a file, I want to skip lines that contain a newline and then move on to the next line. How would I achieve this? The code below doesn't seem to be working.

```
if(!inputStream.nextLine().contains("\n")) {
                ...                   
}
```

Comment: You can't know if there is a new line without consuming a new line.

Comment: The next line would just be empty string isn't it, since whatever reader you're using would probably stripe the line separator.

Comment: That makes sense. I can just use inputStream.nextLine() != "" I was trying to make everything more complicated...

Comment: Don't compare strings with == (or !=). Use equals() or, in this case, isEmpty().